# Symfony2 SonataAdminBundle Password field encryption

Tags: security, symfony, encryption, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I have FOSUserBundle to manage my users, and SonataAdminBundle to manage my website... I have a problem, whenever I try to change/add a password to any user, the password isn't encoded into `sha512`, but it does when the user register itself inside fosuserbundle registration page...

So there isn't any problem with Symfony2 configuration neither fosuserbundle config, it may be inside SonataAdminBundle somewhere, or maybe into my admin class...

```
<?php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Admin/PostAdmin.php

namespace Web\DificilBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Web;

class UserAdmin extends Admin
{
    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password', 'password') // -> I WANT THIS TO BE ENCODED INTO SHA512!
             ->add('roles','choice',array('choices'=>$this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles'),'multiple'=>true ));

            //->add('body')
        ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on filter forms
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password')
        ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on lists
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('facebookid')
            ->add('roles');

            //->add('password', 'password')
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same (inc solution below) applies to Symfony3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution for everyone who has the same problem as me, just on your admin class, where you define your Create/Update form, use this and your password will be perfectly encrypted and ready to log into your new user ;)

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
        ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: I have used this code. It is working in case of add new user but when i update the password of user then that new password in not update in data table of user. So please help where is i am wrong.